# Box-shadow on left and right side not working with ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to apply thins shadow only on right and left side of the section in React Js using Css but I am getting shadow only on one side. Here is the code

```
    .MainSection{
    margin-top:2%;
    background-color: white;
    width: 40%;
    border: solid 1.5px gray;
    box-shadow: -60px 0px 100px -90px #000000,60px 0px 100px -90px #000000;
    
}
```

```
    import React from "react";
import "./MainSection.css";

function MainSection() {
  return (
    <div className="MainSection">
      <h1>MainSection</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainSection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `box-shadow` dimensions have problem. Rest of the `css` works if you change dimensions

```css
.MainSection{
    margin-top:2%;
    background-color: white;
    width: 40%;
    border: solid 1.5px gray;
    box-shadow: 22px 0 15px -4px #000000, -22px 0 8px -4px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainSection">
  <h1>MainSection</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working either , I am getting both the shadows on one side.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add box shadow on the left and right both side

```
box-shadow: -60px 0px 100px -20px #000000, 60px 0px 100px -20px #000000;
```